# How to save the endpoint data in model store if call is made from actions in controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have created a dialog box using the ember-modal-dialog. The content that is going to displayed in the dialog is received from the server. I am able to make the call to server and fetch the data. But I don't know how to save the data into my model store from actions.

Controller.js

```
actions:{
    fiModal1: function(photo){
        Ember.$('body').addClass('centered-modal-showing');
        var currentState = this;
        photo.toggleProperty('fidialogShowing'))
        console.log('opendialog');
        raw({
            url: 'http://example.co.in/api/photo/'+photo.get('like_pk')+'/likes/',
            type: 'GET',
        }).then(function(result){
            currentState.set('model.feed.liker',result)
        });
    },
    bookmarked:function(liker){
       liker.set('is_bookmarked',true)
    },


}
```

feed.hbs

```
<p {{action "fiModal" photo }}>
    {{photo.0.numlikes}}
</p>
{{#if photo.fidialogShowing}}
    {{#modal-dialog translucentOverlay=true close = (action "fiDialogClose" photo)}}
    {{#each model.feed.liker as |liker}}
        <div class = "col-sm-6">
            {{#if liker.is_bookmarked}}
                <a href {{action "unbookmarked" liker}}>
                    <img class="foll" src = "images/button-bookmark-secondary-state-dark-b-g.png">
                </a>
            {{else}}
                <a href {{action "bookmarked" liker}}>
                    <img class="foll" src = "images/button-bookmark.png">
                </a>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}
```

Now the problem is that when action inside the dialog box is fired it throws an error:

```
fiver.set is not function
```

I think that the problem is occurring because I am not saving the result in the model store. How should I do it so the action inside the dialog box also works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just encapsulate the results from your server into Ember.Object

```
Ember.Object.create(json)
```

For exemple replace your line

```
currentState.set('model.feed.liker',result)
```

by

```
currentState.set('model.feed.liker', result.map(function(item) {
  return Ember.Object.create(item);
})
```

that way each elements inside your model.feed.liker should have a method 'set' available.